# PHP ffmpeg failed to save video

Tags: php

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i tmp/160111809213215683.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 upload/video/1601118092_1376831929.mp4
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command
'/usr/bin/ffprobe' 'tmp/160111809213215683.mp4' '-show_streams' '-print_format' 'json':

Error Output:

ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
--incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample
--disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass
--enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite
--enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse
--enable-librsvg --enable-librubb in
**/var/www/panel.telly.network/public_html/api/video_editor/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php** on
line **263**

Comment: hi did you resolved it